# How to send emails with send_mass_mail in Django for more than one recipients dynamically?

Tags: python, django, email

I try to send an email to more than one recipients but I am doing something wrong. I'm using a for loop to get the email addresses from the user. If I print the emails these are in this format: `'someone@xy.com'` and I have more than one.
But if I try to send them the email, only one user gets the it.

It sends the mail every time if the html in the urls.py is refreshed.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail
from somemodels.models import Project
import datetime
import calendar

def emails(request):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    weekday = today.weekday()
    month = datetime.date.today().month
    year = datetime.date.today().year
    cal = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    firstday = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
    subject='hello'
    message='how are you?'
    from_email='myemail@gmail.com'


    for p in Project.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM somemodels_project INNER JOIN auth_user ON auth_user.id = othermodel_project.permitted_users'):
        recipient_list = p.email,
        print(recipient_list)

    if (today == firstday):    
        messages = [(subject, message, from_email, [recipient]) for recipient in recipient_list]
        send_mass_mail(messages) 
    
        print('Successfully sent')
    else:
        print('Not sent') 

    return render(request, 'performance/emails.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'email'
urlpatterns = [

    path('emails/', login_required(views.emails), name='emails'),
```

]

Comment: I think it shuld look like this `(subject, message, from_email, [recipient for recipient in recipient_list]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the list of people to send the email to

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/

```
recipient_list =  Project.objects.raw(...)
```

If your message doesn't change you can also use

```
send_mail(
    subject,
    message,
    from_email,
    [r.email for r in recipient_list],
)
```

If you want to use mass mail because it is more efficient
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/

```
messages = [(subject, message, from_email, [r.email]) for r in recipient_list]

send_mass_mail(messages)
```